# Getting a Syntax Error when Trying to Create a CTE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, common-table-expression

Here's the code:

```
WITH sub_query AS (Select imdp_title_id FROM movie_ratings)
```

Here's the output:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

MySQL version : '8.0.26'

Software Used : MySQL Workbench 8.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you forgetting ; in last bcz it's not in code posted by you?

Comment: A cte by it self only is not runnable code. You must use it in another query.

Comment: Run `select * from sub_query` right after the cte.

Comment: @forpas that fixed the problem, but why do I have to use the sub query right after it was defined, cannot use it later for example?

Comment: You can write a cte or more, separated by commas and after the last one you must write a query that uses one or more of those ctes. You can find more here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/

Comment: @forpas oh I get you now, thanks a lot. Can you write this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: It's fine, there is no need for an answer.

Comment: @forpas If questions are answered only in the comments, then they stay in the "Unanswered" queue forever.

Comment: @BillKarwin not all questions need an answer. A point to the right direction or a link to the documentation in some cases is all that is needed.

Comment: @forpas, I don't agree, and [neither does the Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you have an answer, then post it as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't agree either. If all that it takes to clarify the asker's confusion is a link to the documentation then there is no need for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use CTE syntax, you must define the CTE, and then use that CTE in a DML statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html says:

> The following example defines CTEs named cte1 and cte2 in the WITH
> clause, and refers to them in the top-level SELECT that follows the
> WITH clause:
>
> ```
> WITH
>   cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
>   cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
> SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
> WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
> ```

This shows that you have a final SQL statement following one or more `<cte> AS ( <subquery> )` definitions.

MySQL 8.0 supports `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` DML statements following the CTE's.